# What is the real purpose of ViewModel in MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I had a talk with teamlead about this topic and from his point of view we can just use bindings and commandings omitting ViewModel, because we can test UI behaviour without VM using Automation or our own developed mechanisms of UI testing (based on automated clicks on Views). So, if there are no real benefits, why should I spawn "redundant" entities? Besides, automated integration tests look much more indicative than VM tests. So, it seems that we can mix VMs and Models.

**update:**
I agree that mixing VMs and Models brings into single .cs a data model and rules of data transformation for representing it in a View. But if this is only one benefit - I don't want to create a VM for each View.

So what pros of VM do you know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The VM is the logic behind your UI. combining the UI code with the logic ends up in a mess, at least from my experience. Your view should define what you see - buttons, menus etc. Your VM is in charge of the binding and handling events caused by the user.

**Edit:**
Not wanting to create a VM for each view doesn't sound like a SW-oriented reason. Doing so will leave your view clean of logic and your model free to be the connecting layer between the core layer and your app layer.
I like the following example referring to the model and its role (why it shouldn't be combined with the VM): imagine you're developing some Android app using Google maps. Google maps are your core. Then one fine day you really need the option to, say, color parts of the map in pink, bright pink. An email to Google asking for `colorPink(Map)`will probably get you nowhere. That's where your model steps in and provides you the map wrapper that you need to define your pinky method.
Without a separate model, you'd have to go through every VM that uses `map` and update it.

So, the view has a role, the model has a role, the VM is the logic between those.

**Edit 2:**
There are some cases where there's no need of a model layer - I tended to disagree at first but was convinced after a discussion: In relatively small applications, the model can end up being a redundant wrapper with no added functionality over the core. In such cases, you can use the core objects directly.

Answer (score 4):

What is he binding to? Whatever he is binding to is effectively a view model, whether you call it that or not. If it also doubles as a data model, then you're violating the Single Responsibility Principal (SRP). Essentially, the problem here is that you're lumping together code that is servicing different parts of the application architecture, which will lead to a convoluted mess.

Comment: SRP is just a slogan. I talk about reality. I agree that mixing VMs and Models brings into single .cs a data model and rules of data transformation for representing it in a View. But if this is only one benefit - I don't want to create a VM for each View.

Answer (score 1):

UI Testing is a pain not just because you need to accomodate for changes in the View which can occur many times but also because UI tends to interfere with its own testing. Depending on the tests needed you'll need to keep track of focus, resize and possibly other (mouse) events which can be extremely hard to make it a representative test.

It is much easier to scope the test to the logic in the ViewModel and leave the UI testing to humans. The human testers do not need to test the logic; their only consern should be the UI.

By breaking down a ViewModel into a hierarchy of ViewModels you might be able to reuse a ViewModel multiple times. There is no rule that states that you should have a ViewModel for each View. (After a release or two I end up there but that's besides the point :) )

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the nature of your Model - sometimes they are simple and can serve as both like you are suggesting.  However, depending on the framework, you'll need to dirty up your model with some PropertyChanged event code which can get messy and distracting.  In more complex cases, they serve as a mediator between your the view and the model.  Let's suppose you're creating a client app that monitors a remote process or database entries - creating View Model's for these entities let's you surface your data in a way that is convenient to bind to for a UI framework (but is silly in a DB framework), encapsulate operations as commands, perform validation, etc etc.